# Overwrite workflows file in github actions

Tags: automation, cron, github-actions

I made a simple github action to scrape sports odds and do some live analysis.

In order to not let it run for nothing (like if i put a schedule to launch the code every 5 minutes when we can easily retrive that the next match is in 8 hours), i wanted to schedule the next launch a few minutes before the next interesting games.

I tried to update the yaml file itself but there are some permissions issues.
`! [remote rejected] main -> main (refusing to allow a GitHub App to create or update workflow`.github/workflows/live_basket_matches.yml`without`workflows `permission)`

I tried to get a personalised authorization token with worflows write permission but it didn't work either.

```
name: Cron update

env:
  PAT: ${{ secrets.PAT_WITH_WORKFLOW_SCOPE}}

on: 
 workflow_run:
    workflows: [Basketball Live scrapping]
    types:
      - completed
jobs:
  on-success:
    runs-on: ubuntu-latest
    
     
    if: ${{ github.event.workflow_run.conclusion == 'success' }}
    steps:
      - run: echo 'The triggering workflow passed'
      - name: Checkout repository
        uses: actions/checkout@v2
      
      - name: Use the PAT in an environment variable
        run: |
          echo $PAT
      - name: Set up Python
        uses: actions/setup-python@v2
        with:
          python-version: 3.x # replace with your desired version

      - name: Run script
        run: python modif_cron.py # replace with the name of your script

      - name: Commit results
        run: |
          git config --local user.name "$GITHUB_ACTOR"
          git config --local user.email "$GITHUB_ACTOR@users.noreply.github.com"
          git add -A
          git commit -m 'cron modif'
          git push origin main
  on-failure:
    runs-on: ubuntu-latest
    if: ${{ github.event.workflow_run.conclusion == 'failure' }}
    steps:
      - run: echo 'The triggering workflow failed'
```

```
import os
import re

with open(".\.github\workflows\live_basket_matches.yml", 'r') as file:
    filedata = file.read()

filedata = re.sub("cron\s*:\s*\'(.*?)'\s*\n\njobs", "cron :"+cron_launch+"\n\njobs", filedata)

with open('.\.github\workflows\live_basket_matches.yml', 'w') as file:
    file.write(filedata)
```

Of course I'm open to alternatives !

Answer (score 0):

1. Create a PAT with workflow permission if not exists.
2. Follow `(Repository) Settings > Security > Secrets and variables > Actions > New repository secret`, add the token as secret to the repository.
3. Add the secret in `actions/checkout` step, just like this:

```yaml
- uses: actions/checkout@v3
  with:
    token: ${{ secrets.WORKFLOW_OVERWRITE_TOKEN }}
```